# О цели высказывания

Tags: синтаксис

В связи с вопросом о цели высказывания предложения "До свидания, журавли!", которое относится к повествовательным. Мне не совсем ясно, что в нём сообщается. А вот предложение "Здравствуйте." Мы отнесём к побудительным (здесь глагол в повелительном наклонении). А разве у этих предложений не одна цель высказывания - пожелание?

Comment: @ХэшКод, я я что-то не поняла Ваших изменений. Почему строчная буква в середине предложения заменена на заглавную?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"До свидания, журавли!"- нечленимое предложение, вокативно - междометное. (Предложения, основу которых составляет обращение, называются вокативными). В большинстве случаев этикетные формулы упоподобляются знаменательным словам,  которые утратили или утрачивают свое лексическое значение и превращаются в междометные выражения (спасибо, здравствуй и под.)"До свидания" уподобляется неполному предложению "расстаёмся до следующего свидания", но оно синонимично междометному выражению  "прощайте".Это тоже междометное предложение.

Междометные предложения характеризуются не по цели высказывания, а по коммуникативной функции и по интонации.  Это предложения, выражающие 1) эмоциональную реакцию говорящего; 2) его волевую реакцию; 3) модальную оценку мысли собеседника или собственной мысли; 4) предложения, выполняющие контактоустанавливающую функцию.

До свидания!-формула вежливости, значит, функция контактоустанавливающая.

Журавли!-вокативное предложение. Вокативные предложения могут выражать два типа реакций говорящего: а) эмоциональные и б) волевые (побудительные). В нашем случае побудительность отсутствует.Она есть в команде:"Рядовой Иванов!"- и тот откликается и производит действие(шаг вперёд или что-то ещё).

Таким образом, характеристика предложения будет следующая:предложение нечленимое, вокативно-междометное с контактоустанавливающей функцией и эмоциональным вокативом (или риторическим), восклицательное по интонации.

Comment: Людмила, так ведь обращение тут совсем не главное. Можно и опустить.
Останется "До свидания", "Счастливого пути!" а то и вовсе "Добрый день!" 
Какой уж тут вокатив...
Вот насчет отнесения подобных предложений к междометным - это интересно... 
Это из Академической грамматики, или что новоизобретенное? Где смотреть?

Comment: Споры о них ещё идут. Мнений у учёных было много, куда их относить, сошлись на том,что это особая группа предложений-высказываний, правда, называют их по-разному. Этикетные формулы теперь называют высказыванием (в отличие от предложения),словом-предложением, междометным предложением.Вот вузовский учебник В. П. Малащенко для филологов:  http://rudocs.exdat.com/docs/index-23108.html?page=2

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что здесь тоже обычное повествовательное предложение. Хотя это смотря как его как сказать, с каким тоном...

Такие предложения как "Будьте счастливы", "Выздоравливайте", "Всего доброго", "Спокойной ночи" и проч. - и особенно "Здравствуйте!", "пожалуйста" (="Пожалуй, старый"), "Спасибо" (="Спаси тебя Бог!") - давно потеряли прямое значение и превратились в атрибут вежливости. По смыслу их трудно отнести к побудительным. То, что в них присутствуют глаголы повелительного наклонения или прямые пожелания, не должно смущать. Формальная грамматика нередко расходится с фактическим смыслом, выбирая самые разные выразительные средства для одних и тех же мыслей.

Comment: Похоже, было бы неплохо "организовать" такие предложения в отдельную группу.

Comment: Но и кповествовательным их, на мой взгляд, отнести тоже нельзя: в них ничего не сообщается.